# JavaScript to convert xml sitemap into usable links?

Tags: php, javascript, sitemap

I have a site that I made using weebly, so I don't have many customizable items such as search boxes and stuff but I do know of atomz search. The only issue is that they require links to get to pages on the site and I have some hidden pages that I want included. I am not even sure if this is possible but can I convert an XML sitemap (weebly generates one automatically) formatted as:

```
<url>
<loc>
http://kingdomofmuqtasid.weebly.com/1/post/2012/7/welcome-to-my-site-and-welcome-to-me.html
</loc>
<lastmod>2012-07-14</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>
http://kingdomofmuqtasid.weebly.com/1/post/2012/7/summers.html
</loc>
<lastmod>2012-07-14</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>
http://kingdomofmuqtasid.weebly.com/1/post/2012/7/apple-technology-of-the-future.html
</loc>
<lastmod>2012-07-14</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
```

Now is there any way to take the url's and turn document.write as links? If it isn't possible with javascript, I have a local apache setup that I can use to test PHP scripts, will PHP work then?

Thanks!

Comment: Can someone please help me here? I really would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You are asking a heavy question which has several solutions.  You should do a little more googling before coming back, but here's to get you started.

**Option 1:** Use AJAX to load the sitemap (xml) file, parse the XML, and build/insert hyperlinks.  I suggest you use jQuery for all of these steps.  This would be the quickest and easiest solution, but has side effects for SEO, maintainability, etc.

**Option 2:** Use PHP to parse the sitemap (xml) file and build hyperlinks on the server.  This solution will require a little more knowledge and will probably take a little longer... but is the better solution IMO.

Comment: Thanks, but can you please show me the Ajax code? I really have no experience with Ajax...

Comment: Sorry for the late response... but that's the part you should Google.  You should at least make an attempt to learn how to make an AJAX call, and come back for more help.  You will need 1) jQuery, 2) the location of your sitemap file, 3) familiarity with using jQuery and writing HTML.  There are plenty of tutorials out there, and even people who have been in your exact situation: http://www.vagrantradio.com/2009/10/how-to-parse-xml-using-jquery-and-ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use simplexml_load_file() function in PHP like this:

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file ('sitemap.xml');

foreach ($xml->url as $url)
{
    print ("$url->loc\n");
}

?>
```

Note that your entire XML doc should be embraced in a single tag:

```
<mydoc>
  <url> .. </url>
  <url> .. </url>
  <url> .. </url>
</mydoc>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a old style HTML editor and notepad. Paste contents into notepad and just delete what is not a URL link.  Then copy into HTML editor. Next copy each URL into the link maker and paste it in.  Slow yes, but it works. Then save.